# Getting winners from database per position - Voting system

Tags: mysql, join, voting

So I have my data in the table in this format

```
Candidate Name      Position ID       Total Votes
_____________     _____________     _____________
Name 1                   1                 1
Name 2                   1                 3
Name 3                   2                 1
Name 4                   2                 4
Name 5                   3                 1
Name 6                   3                 5
```

How can I get the each winners per position. I try many queries but didnt get the right results. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `GROUPBY` and `MAX`? Is there a query you've tried to write yourself?

Comment: Yes. I have tried select groupby and max. I even tried subquery. But still failed.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: And if you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I have tried this "SELECT first_name, position_id, votes 
FROM `candidates`
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(votes) AS winner FROM candidates ) AS T
ON T.winner = candidates.votes
WHERE event_id = 3
GROUP BY position_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution which could be slightly naïve but I can't seem to be able to think of a better version.

Let us consider a table with the details as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE VOTING (Name TEXT, position integer, votes integer);
INSERT INTO VOTING VALUES("Name 1", 1, 1);
INSERT INTO VOTING VALUES("Name 2", 1, 3);
INSERT INTO VOTING VALUES("Name 3", 2, 1);
INSERT INTO VOTING VALUES("Name 4", 2, 4);
INSERT INTO VOTING VALUES("Name 5", 3, 1);
INSERT INTO VOTING VALUES("Name 6", 3, 5);
```

Query is:

```
SELECT name, 
       A.position, 
       votes 
FROM   voting A, 
       (SELECT position, 
               Max(votes) AS M 
        FROM   voting 
        WHERE  position IN (SELECT DISTINCT( position ) 
                            FROM   voting) 
        GROUP  BY position) B 
WHERE  A.position = B.position 
       AND A.votes = B.m;
```

My thought process was as follows:

- First select all possible distinct `position` values.
- For each distinct `position` retrieve the `max(votes)` for that position.
- Attach the `max(votes)` column to the original table where `position` values match, so that means for each row and position pair there is a max(votes) for that position available.
- Filter this new table where position matches and original vote value matches the max(votes) value and you have the table. You can further order these however you want `(ASC/DESC)`

The result is as follows:

```
Name    position    votes
------  --------    -----
Name 2  1           3
Name 4  2           4
Name 6  3           5
```

Here's a link to a running sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d7ce6/54/0

Comment: Why am I getting errors in my MySQL after trying your code out?

Comment: Thank you sudheesh. Finally got it running. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Let your table be denoted by `t`. Note that this query does give all winners with the maximum amount of votes.

```
with position_max(position, max_vote) as
(
    select position, max(votes)
    from t
    group by position
)
select t.name, t.position
from t, position_max
where t.position=position_max.position and t.votes=position_max.max_vote;
```

Without the `with`-clause:

```
select t.name, t.position
from t
join (
    select position, max(votes) as votes
    from t
    group by position
) ta on ta.position=t.position
where t.votes=ta.votes;
```

Comment: WITH is unrecognizable statement. Im using Mysql.

Comment: @SonsonIxon Actually the lateset version supports CTE